# Trouble copying files from folder to different folders

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to loop over the files witch start with 'R008' in the directory and copy them to the different folders (which are all in the same directory).

```
import shutil
import os
source = 'D:\\source_folder\\'
dest1 = 'D:\\destination_folder\\' 

folder_name = input("What day of the month? ")
folder_path = (dest1 + folder_name)
i = 1

files = os.listdir(source)

for file in files:
    if file.startswith('R008'):
        if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path)
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), folder_path)

        if os.path.exists(folder_path):
            os.makedirs(folder_path + "_" + str(i))
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), folder_path + "_" + str(i))
            i += 1
```

My problem is the first file is always copied twice. 5 folders are created for 4 files [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOv1a.png). And I don't understend why

Comment: Helma, in your code you do 1st copy here: "shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), folder_path)" under first (if) condition. You also create new folder there: os.makedirs(folder_path). Immediately afterwards you check if folder exist (if os.path.exists(folder_path):) and it obviously does, so if you get into first (if), you also get into second (if) and do another shutil.copy here

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent tests, and the body of the first `if` makes (by creating `folder_path`) the condition for the second `if` (`folder_path` exists) true. So you end up performing both copies. If you want to only copy to the root path, and not also copy to the extended path, just make the second `if` into an `else` tied to the original `if`, e.g.:

```
    if not os.path.exists(folder_path):
        os.makedirs(folder_path)
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), folder_path)
    else:  # Could be elif os.path.exists(folder_path), but you literally just verified it doesn't exist
        os.makedirs(folder_path + "_" + str(i))
        shutil.copy(os.path.join(source, file), folder_path + "_" + str(i))
        i += 1
```